# React Router v6 - how to handle nested routes but with only current page showing instead of previous pages

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am trying to understand how to handle nested routes but with different pages using react-router v6.

For instance, say the "/" path returns a list of companies. ":companyId" takes you to the company page and ":/productId" takes you to the product of that company.

What I would like to know is how to only show the content page for that product instead of showing the list of products and the list of companies too.

I think this should be nested as I need the underlying params of both company id and product id to know where I am. How do I properly use Outlet in this case?

Companies has a list of companies. Company has a list of products.

My routes currently:

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <Companies />,
    children: [
      {
        path: ":companyId",
        element: <Company />,
        children: [{ path: ":productId", element: <Product /> }],
      },
    ],
  },
]
```

---

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    children: [
      {
        index: true,
        element: <Companies />,
      },
      {
        path: ":companyId",
        children: [
          { index: true, element: <Company /> },
          { path: ":productId", element: <Product /> },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

Comment: You can do this without nested routers aswell but am curious is the pathname which redirects right?

Comment: how do you get the company id if you are in the product page if its not nested?
say something like brands/lenovo/laptop-1234

Comment: Just send it through param and get it through use params over there

Comment: const up =(id)=>{
    navigate(`/assignment/${id}`, { replace: true });
}

Comment: const{id}=useParams()

Comment: What have you tried? We can't help debug code we can't see. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: The problem is I dont want to see the list of companies or the list of products when I am in a specific product page.  Don't I have to be in a specific company's route to access the product?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question/issue correctly, it seems that `Companies` is rendered as a layout component, in other words, it is rendered along with the nested children routes, but you want one or the other.

If you want to render one or the other then move `Companies` down into a child route, specifically as an index route, so it is rendered when the path is exactly `"/"` but not when another nested route matches.

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    children: [
      {
        index: true,
        element: <Companies />,
      },
      {
        path: ":companyId",
        element: <Company />,
        children: [
          {
            path: ":productId",
            element: <Product />
          }
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
]
```

Comment: I have updated my question again. This seems like what I need but am not sure if this is the correct way to navigate to a product using v6.

Comment: @Riyaz This is just a routes structure, how you navigate to them is independent of it. Are you having issue navigating to these routes?

Comment: Well, I wanted to fix this routes structure first before I moved into passing data between the elements. For now I have params which gives me both the company id and product id. Thank you for clarifying that part.
Now I am wondering how to pass data from this company element to the product element.  Just Id alone isn't enough.

What I have tried: I tried using Outlet and passing data to its context but I get undefined because the "parent" is an index route now.

Comment: @Riyaz Depending on where the "source of truth" is (*i.e. Redux state, React Context, state in `App`, state in parent component, etc...*) you will need to access accordingly. You could also send product data in route state (*`navigate(path, { state: { ...product thing ... } })`*), but you would need to then save the product on the receiving route and persist it in case of page reload. Using a Context is fairly simple if you haven't upgraded to Redux just yet.

Comment: @Riyaz I don't see any issues with the route structure. `Route` components render an `Outlet` by default if no `element` is specified, and index routes are specifically for matching the path the layout/Outlet is rendered on. I think you're good there if using the index routes resolved your question/issue.